# Deserialize polymorphic json object with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I actually try to deserialize the next object in a unit test in accordance with [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/platform/documentation/api)

```
string json = @"{
            ""data"": {
                ""attributes"": {
                    ""about"": """",
                    ""created"": ""2017-04-01T12:00:00+00:00"",
                    ""discord_id"": null,
                    ""email"": ""james@mymail.com"",
                    ""facebook"": null,
                    ""facebook_id"": null,
                    ""first_name"": ""Firstname"",
                    ""full_name"": ""Fullname"",
                    ""gender"": 0,
                    ""has_password"": true,
                    ""image_url"": ""https://c3.patreon.com/2/patreon-user/abc.jpg"",
                    ""is_deleted"": false,
                    ""is_email_verified"": true,
                    ""is_nuked"": false,
                    ""is_suspended"": false,
                    ""last_name"": """",
                    ""social_connections"": {
                        ""deviantart"": null,
                        ""discord"": null,
                        ""facebook"": null,
                        ""spotify"": null,
                        ""twitch"": null,
                        ""twitter"": null,
                        ""youtube"": null
                    },
                    ""thumb_url"": ""https://c3.patreon.com/2/patreon-user/abc.jpg"",
                    ""twitch"": null,
                    ""twitter"": null,
                    ""url"": ""https://www.patreon.com/user?u=123456"",
                    ""vanity"": null,
                    ""youtube"": null
                },
                ""id"": ""123456"",
                ""relationships"": {
                    ""pledges"": {
                        ""data"": []
                    }
                },
                ""type"": ""user""
            },
            ""links"": {
                ""self"": ""https://api.patreon.com/user/123456""
            }
            }";
```

But my attributes object or array is polymorphic, it can be User like my exemple but other object types, and I don't know how to do.
I tried something like [that](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) but without success.

And second question, how is it possible to flattern attributes in same user class with id and relationships.

EDIT:
To anwser to my question, I found a better solution than "Duplicate" :
http://jsonapi.org/

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not gonna work.

The Newtonsoft.JSON package has [options to include type names](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) when you serialize an object, so deserializing works correctly with polymorphism.  But with your plain JSON, the deserializer has no way of knowing which class to instantiate inside your array.